# Blender Inset not working as expected

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

Probably a silly oversight on my part but I'm having trouble with using inset.

I'm constructing the mug from this video [Blender Beginner Tutorial - Part 5: Modelling] The image shows where I'm up to (screen shot is of my model).

[image: Screenshot]

I'm trying to do an inset circle on the top face before extruding down inside the cup. However, when I press <kbd>i</kbd> for *Inset* Blender changes to inset mode and I get the dotted line from the centre of the selected face out to the cursor, along with the *Confirm: Enter/LClick...* in the bottom bar, but the inset doesn't actually work.

No scalable inner circle/face appears. It feels like I have something switched on that shouldn't be but I have no idea what it is.

Any help would be much appreciated. The Blender file is here: [Donuts & Coffee Cup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DWfIMJ2SXobUJlYVcxV1dJeUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of your model instead, the video doesn't help us diagnose what you are doing wrong

Comment: Cant you see the screen shot above?  my model is also available from the link 'Donuts & Coffee Cup'

Comment: The text mentions "*The image shows where I'm up to*" and I read that as meaning it was a screenshot from the video tutorial. My bad, you are good then.

Comment: Oh sorry. For a minute I thought the image wasnt showing for anyone but me. Have updated the text to avoid the confusion. Cheers.

Comment: Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: @cegaton much obliged

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your object is scaled to a factor of `0.003` and it is messing up with operator values and property scaling. In object mode apply the scale to your object by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*.

Also your scene seems to have *Unit Scale* is at `0.001`, which might also be messing up with scaling factors. See if you need to adjust it at the *Properties Window > Scene > Units* tab

Comment: Many thanks. Applying scale fixed it. I set the object units to mm, I presume that's why it's 0.001. Anyway changed the value to 1, and now I have my grid plane back too :o) many thanks again.